# React-Native: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'MainApplication.java'

Tags: react-native

I am running `react-native link` in my React Native project directory.

When running this I am getting the error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/**********/f8app/android/app/src/main/java/com/facebook/f8/MainApplication.java'
```

However, this file does exist.

Full output:

```
(@):f8app *************$ react-native link
{ Error: Cannot find module '/Users/************/f8app/node_modules/moment/package.json'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:455:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:403:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at getRNPMConfig (/Users/***********/f8app/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/rnpm/core/src/config/index.js:13:10)
    at Object.getDependencyConfig (/Users/************/f8app/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/rnpm/core/src/config/index.js:38:14)
    at /Users/**************/f8app/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/rnpm/link/src/getDependencyConfig.js:11:24
    at Array.reduce (native)
    at getDependencyConfig (/Users/***********/f8app/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/rnpm/link/src/getDependencyConfig.js:8:15)
    at link (/Users/***********/f8app/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/rnpm/link/src/link.js:114:22) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
? What is your CodePush deployment key for Android (hit <ENTER> to ignore) 
rnpm-link info Linking react-native-code-push android dependency 
rnpm-link ERR! It seems something went wrong while linking. Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/***********/f8app/android/app/src/main/java/com/facebook/f8/MainApplication.java' 
Please file an issue here: https://github.com/rnpm/rnpm/issues 
/Users/*****************/f8app/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/lib/done.js:10
      throw err;
      ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/**********/f8app/android/app/src/main/java/com/facebook/f8/MainApplication.java'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:640:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:508:33)
    at applyPatch (/Users/***********/f8app/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/rnpm/link/src/android/patches/applyPatch.js:6:29)
    at registerNativeAndroidModule (/Users/**********/f8app/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/rnpm/link/src/android/registerNativeModule.js:23:3)
    at /Users/***********/f8app/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/rnpm/link/src/link.js:55:5
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: You need to set a Deployment Key. Did you followed all the steps? [Check Installation guide on Android](https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-code-push/blob/master/docs/setup-android.md)